# Как вывести значение из этого кода?

Tags: javascript

```js
function readBlob(opt_startByte, opt_stopByte) {

  var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
  if (!files.length) {
    alert('Please select a file!');
    return;
  }


  var file = files[0];
  var start = parseInt(opt_startByte) || 0;
  var stop = parseInt(opt_stopByte) || file.size - 1;

  var reader = new FileReader();

  // If we use onloadend, we need to check the readyState.
  reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
      document.getElementById('byte_content').textContent = evt.target.result;
      document.getElementById('byte_range').textContent = ['Read bytes: ', start + 1, ' - ', stop + 1,
        ' of ', file.size, ' byte file'
      ].join('');
    }
  };

  var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
  reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
}


document.querySelector('.readBytesButtons').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  if (evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'button') {
    var startByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-startbyte');
    var endByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-endbyte');
    readBlob(startByte, endByte);
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<style>
  #byte_content {
    margin: 5px 0;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  #byte_range {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
</style>

<input type="file" id="files" name="file" />Read bytes:
<span class="readBytesButtons">
  <button data-startbyte="0" data-endbyte="4">1-5</button>
  <button data-startbyte="5" data-endbyte="14">6-15</button>
  <button data-startbyte="6" data-endbyte="7">7-8</button>
  <button>entire file</button>
</span>
<div id="byte_range"></div>
<div id="byte_content"></div>
```

Возникла проблема вывода номера, а именно нужно вывести номер автоматически который следует после слов Read bytes: N - N of N byte file:, а не только после нажатия одной из четырех кнопок, пробовал через setInterval не выходит

Comment: что простите? Что именно вы хотите?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял: вы хотите, чтобы при выборе файла сразу показывался результат аналогичный нажатию последней кнопки, в таком случае, просто добавьте обработчик события *onchange* для элемента *input*

например так:

```
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', readBlob);
```

```js
function readBlob(opt_startByte, opt_stopByte) {

  var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
  if (!files.length) {
    alert('Please select a file!');
    return;
  }


  var file = files[0];
  var start = parseInt(opt_startByte) || 0;
  var stop = parseInt(opt_stopByte) || file.size - 1;

  var reader = new FileReader();

  // If we use onloadend, we need to check the readyState.
  reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
      document.getElementById('byte_content').textContent = evt.target.result;
      document.getElementById('byte_range').textContent = ['Read bytes: ', start + 1, ' - ', stop + 1,
        ' of ', file.size, ' byte file'
      ].join('');
    }
  };

  var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
  reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', readBlob);

document.querySelector('.readBytesButtons').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  if (evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'button') {
    var startByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-startbyte');
    var endByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-endbyte');
    readBlob(startByte, endByte);
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<style>
  #byte_content {
    margin: 5px 0;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  #byte_range {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
</style>

<input type="file" id="files" name="file" />Read bytes:
<span class="readBytesButtons">
  <button data-startbyte="0" data-endbyte="4">1-5</button>
  <button data-startbyte="5" data-endbyte="14">6-15</button>
  <button data-startbyte="6" data-endbyte="7">7-8</button>
  <button>entire file</button>
</span>
<div id="byte_range"></div>
<div id="byte_content"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, только остался 1 вопрос : как передать это значение в Mysql?

Comment: @Fukidsa, это уже совсем другой вопрос, обычно если у вас веб страница и инпут типа file - вы кладете его в форму и делаете ей submit - принимаете на сервере, и уже сервер сам думает что и куда, хоть в базу хоть просто на диск сохранить. Кстати для этого не нужно даже _FileReader_ использовать

Comment: Только начинаю постигать Javascript, вообще как можно сделать такое отправление без FileReader?

Comment: Просто файл обновляется несколько раз в минуту и я хочу чтобы данные отправлялись на сервер раз в N секунд

Comment: @Fukidsa, можете просто задать еще один вопрос. с описание что делаете, что хотите чтобы получилось, и что именно не получается :-)